# how to use complex variable as object key in vue data mustache expression?

Tags: vue.js

in a loop, each item is an object. I have to use its value as another object's key.

for vue.js

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
         <p>{{ jss }}</p>
         <table>
             <tr v-for="man in lst">
                 <th>{{ man.name }}</th>
                 <td>{{jss.man.name}}]</td> <!-- not corrrect -->
                 <td>{{jss[man.name]}}]</td> <!-- not corrrect too-->
             </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               message: 'My first VueJS Task',
               jss: {"n1": 999},
               lst: [
                   {"name": "n1"},
                   {"name": "n2"}
                   ]
            }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

above cannot work. it plains 'jss.man.name' or 'jss[man.name]' is not a good expression. what I want is 999

Comment: Not sure what's not working. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-h3cow - the second one does what you're after. There is one issue with you adding an extra "]" after the closing }} but that's just visual - it will still return 999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand fundamentally what your code is doing.

When you have an expression of the form `first.second`, you're roughly requesting that your code retrieve the value named `second` from the object named `first`. Note that `jss.man.name` would then mean "retrieve the value called `man` from the object `jss`, and then retrieve the value called `name` from `man`". Your object called `jss` does not contain anything called `man`, however, so this will return `undefined`, and `undefined` definitely does not contain a value named `name`. In fact, when you try to retrieve the value of a property from `undefined`, you'll get an error, and when you get an error Vue will make it look like nothing is working at all.

What you're really trying to do is find the value named `name` in the object named `man`, and then use this `name` to retrieve a value from `jss`. This looks like `jss[man.name]`, which is one of the solutions you have in place. Simply omit the `jss.man.name` and your code should work:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
         <p>{{ jss }}</p>
         <table>
             <tr v-for="man in lst">
                 <th>{{ man.name }}</th>
                 <!--<td>{{jss.man.name}}]</td> commenting this out should fix it! -->
                 <td>{{jss[man.name]}}</td> <!-- this should be correct-->
             </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               message: 'My first VueJS Task',
               jss: {"n1": 999},
               lst: [
                   {"name": "n1"},
                   {"name": "n2"}
                   ]
            }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

As noted elsewhere, you also had an extra `]` being rendered as well. I've removed that in the code snippet above.

Answer (score -1):

You did an extra ] in the end of one way data binding code. You can update the code like

```
<td>{{jss.man[name]}}</td>
```

or you can use,

```
<td>{{jss.man["name"]}}</td>
```

or,

```
<td>{{jss.man.name}}</td>
```